# Open Alacritty terminal emulator on keyboard shortcut

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

Using Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts, I am able to open a terminal emulator like I'm used to do on i3wm, the problem is that it opens up xterminal-emulator by default, is there a way to open Alacritty instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume you are using the default Ubuntu desktop environment which is GNOME.

Under GNOME you can go to the keyboard settings and add a custom keyboard shortcut and assign something you like to launch Alacritty.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to change the default terminal that opens when you use the default keyboard shortcut?

Open your favorite terminal and enter:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Then, using the number, set the new default and then press enter.